# How is this format a line integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, line-integrals

Here is the format of some line integrals provided by a textbook I was reading:
[image]

I was looking at the last one and noticed that a lot of line integrals are put in that format. However, to me, it looks like we are simply just solving a normal integral (area under the curve) for some function that changes due to x and then we solve a completely different normal integral with a different function who changes due to y. Ideally, it looks like we're solving two unrelated integrals for two unrelated functions in terms of how one changes due to x and the other to y and the only thing related between them is that they're between the same boundaries A and B.

I was wondering how this translates to solving a line function and what each section means?

Edit: To simplify for anybody passing by. Are the f1 and f2 function simply the "height" of the contour? As in, I could define a contour from A to B and the area under that contour (i.e. the height) would be defined by f1 and f2?

Comment: It is unwise to think of integration in terms of "heights" once you reach multivariable calculus. It is better to start thinking of integration as collecting some amount of an object at some points in space.

Answer (score 4):

### Motivation

In the last integral
$$
f_1 (x, y) dx + f_2 (x, y ) dy
$$
is a $1$-form. In fact, it is the most general $1$-form that can exist over $2$ variables.

A $1$-form is something that "eats" a vector and "spits out" a real number. Here's what happens when our one form eats the vector $(a,b)$:
$$
[f_1( x,y) dx + f_2 (x,y) dy](a,b) = f_1 (x,y) a + _2(x, y) b
$$

We can think about integration of $1$-forms by going back to the Riemann sum notion of an integral.

Recall that if $a = x_0 < x_1 <\cdots < x_n = b$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, then
$$
\sum_i f(x_i) \Delta x_i \approx \int_a^b f(x) dx
$$
Now we want to integrate over a curve $c : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$. Using the Riemann sum idea, we take the partition $a = t_0 < \cdots < t_n = b$ and write something like:
$$
\int_c f(x,y) ds \approx \sum_i f(c(t_i) ) [c(t_{i + 1}) - c(t_i)]
$$
But there's a problem. The integral on the left should give us a real number, but the sum on the right is going to give us a vector (if it converges at all). But wait! We have something that turns vectors into real numbers: our $1$-form.

We try instead:
\begin{align}
\int_c & f_1 (x,y) dx + f_2 (x,y) dy 
\\& \approx \sum_i [f_1 (c(t_i)) dx + f_2 (c(t_i)) dy] [c(t_{i + 1}) - c(t_i)]
\end{align}
To see how we can rewrite this in a more computationally friendly way, make the approximation:
$$
c(t_{i + 1}) - c(t_i) \approx c'(t_i) \Delta t_i = (c_1'(t_i) , c_2 ' (t_i)) \Delta t_i = (c_1 ' (t_i) \Delta t_i , c_2 ' (t_i) \Delta t_i)
$$
where we've written $c'(t_i) = (c_1 ' (t_i) , c_2 ' (t_i))$. Plugging this into our integral approximation, we get:
\begin{align}
\int_c & f_1 (x,y) dx + f_2 (x,y) dy 
\\& \approx \sum_i [f_1 (c(t_i)) dx + f_2 (c(t_i)) dy] [c(t_{i + 1}) - c(t_i)]
\\& \approx \sum_i [f_1 (c(t_i)) dx + f_2 (c(t_i)) dy] [(c_1 ' (t_i) \Delta t_i, c_2 ' (t_i) \Delta t_i) ]
\\&= \sum_i f_1 (c(t_i)) c_1 ' (t_i) \Delta t_i + f_2 (c(t_i)) c_2 ' (t_i) \Delta t_i
\\&= \sum_i f_1 (c(t_i)) c_1 ' (t_i) \Delta t_i + \sum_i f_2 (c(t_i)) c_2 ' (t_i) \Delta t_i
\\&\approx \int_a^b f_1 (c(t)) c_1'(t) dt + \int_a^b f_2 (c(t)) c_2'(t) dt
\end{align}

### Answer

To answer your question:
$$
\int_c f_1 (x,y) dx + f_2 (x,y) dy = \int_a^b f_1 (c(t)) c_1'(t) dt + \int_a^b f_2 (c(t)) c_2'(t) dt
$$
where $c : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a curve that starts at $A$ and ends at $B$.

### Commentary

Regrettably, it is still common practice to teach that $\int fdx + gdy = \int (f,g) \cdot (dx, dy)$. I'm going to encourage you to think of an object like $fdx + gdy$ as a $1$-form with its own life, not as the "dot product" $(f,g) \cdot (dx, dy)$. A $1$-form is simply something that wants to be integrated over a curve.

As for interpretation, in the $1$-form
$$
f_1 (x,y) dx + f_2 (x,y) dy
$$
you can think that $f_1$ is how heavily we weight movement in the $x$ direction, and $f_2$ is how heavily we weight movement in the $y$ direction. So if we integrate the $1$-form $f(x,y) dx$ along a path that moves only in the $y$ direction, we expect to get $0$, which we do.

Answer (score 2):

The last one is the vector form of a line integral. Say you have a force $\vec{F}$ and you want to find out how much work $W$ it does along the path defined by $\vec{r}(t)$. Then a small work $dW$ will be given by

\begin{align}
dW &= \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}' \\
\implies W &= \int_{C} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}'
\end{align}
where $C$ is the curve defined by $\vec{r}(t)$. This is a line integral no doubt, since you are integrating on an arbitrary path $\vec{r}(t)$. In general, $\vec{F}(t)$ can be any vector field, not necessarily only a force, and $W$ is in general the $\textbf{circulation}$ of the vector field $\vec{F}$ on the curve $C$.

Now say you are using a Cartesian coordinate system. For your question, let's confine ourselves to two dimensions though this method is completely general and will hold in $n$ dimensions.

Then you can break your vector fields into their $x$ and $y$ components.
\begin{align}
\vec{F}(t) &= f_1(x(t), y(t)) \vec{i} + f_2( x(t), y(t) ) \vec{j} \\
\vec{r}(t) &= x(t) \, \vec{i} + y(t) \, \vec{j} \\
\implies \vec{r}'(t) &= x'(t) \, \vec{i} + y'(t) \, \vec{j} \\
\end{align}
Therefore the dot product $\vec{F}(t) \cdot \vec{r}(t)$ will be,
\begin{equation}
\vec{F}(t) \cdot \vec{r}(t) = f_1(x(t), y(t)) \, x'(t) + f_2(x(t), y(t)) \, y'(t)
\end{equation}

Finally, the circulation will be
\begin{align}
W &= \int_{C} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}' \\
  &= \int_{t_A}^{t_B} \vec{F}(t) \cdot \vec{r}'(t) dt \\
  &= \int_{t_A}^{t_B} f_1(x(t), y(t)) \, x'(t) dt + f_2(x(t), y(t)) \, y'(t) dt \\
  &= \int_{A}^{B} f_1(x, y) \, dx + f_2(x, y) \, dy \\
\end{align}
where in the last step I've used the substitution $x'(t) dt = dx$ and $y'(t) = dy$ to remove the parameter $t$. If you look at the equation it is precisely what is mentioned as your last example.

This is the form of a line integral expressed in the form of ordinary integrals. Both the integrals separately are just regular integrals, but their combination will represent a line integral. Can you think how to do this for $n$ dimensions?